# Firebase: Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword doesn't exist

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I've been trying to setup a default login system (while I create the rest of the app), so right now i just want my app to authenticate with my credentials (only 1 user, in dev), but I can't access the method the [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_in_existing_users) says to use.

When I try to call the method, this is what the auto complete says

[image: What I see]

Basically, looking for a method like this

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // code
}
```

Comment: use: firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)

Comment: @AshishSharma tried that, method still doesn't exist for me [What Happens](https://imgur.com/a/AgBOc)

Comment: bro you are using 'Firebase', try 'firebase'.

Comment: how do I create that variable? I never made that variable, I only have the global Firebase object that I import (and setup in ```AppDelegate.swift``` with ```FirebaseApp.configure()```

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you are importing both:

   ```
   import Firebase 

   import FirebaseAuth
   ```
2. For sign in, Call this function and do your task inside completion handler:

   ```
   FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: username, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in

   })
   ```
3. for Sign up, do this:

   ```
   FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: "\(username)", password: "\(pass)", completion: { (user,error) in })
   ```

Comment: I figured it out thanks to this, only difference it is ```Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail etc```

if you can make that addition to your answer, that'd be awesome, but thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for upvoting, and Maybe you have created Auth as an object of FIRAuth, still, you can use either of these.

Comment: Fairly certain that Auth is the new FIRAuth with Firebase 4 :P

Comment: @RonakShah  okay maybe i'm not aware of that as I've not worked on firebase recently. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, you still helped immensely, thanks agian!

Answer (score -1):

install angularfire2 this will solve the problem

Comment: This question is about iOS, not angular.